# Joomla. How to edit the link of the Menu in default.php?

Tags: php, joomla, menu

I want to edit Menu in Joomla.

Me need to replace

```
<li class="item-101 default"><a href="/2/index.php">Светлое</a></li>
```

on

```
<li class="item-101 default"><a href="/2/index.php"><span class="MyClass">Светлое</span></a></li>
```

I think this is done in this file
`nameTemplate\modules\mod_menu\tmpl\default.php`

or
`nameTemplate\modules\mod_menu\tmpl\default_url.php`

But I can not solve the problem. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Copy modules/mod_menu/tmpl/default.php
- ...to /templates/nameTemplate/html/mod_menu/default.php

This will override the default menu template file. In the copied file, add the following inside the foreach-loo around line 22 ( `<?php foreach ($list as $i => &$item)`):

```
if($item->id == 101) {
  $item->title = "<span class=\"MyClass\">{$item->title}</span>";
}
```

This should add a span with your own class on menu item 101.

(Still, Lovntola's answer should solve your problem in an easier way)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class label under the option tab of this menu entry. This class label will add the class Name to the link

Comment: Thank you, but this did not solve the problem. Need add span

Comment: Can you not change (or add) your CSS from [span.MyClass] to [li.MyClass > a] ?

Comment: No, I need to add a span. XD

Comment: Then override the menu component in the template und modify the menu component.